# What kind of settings/method calls will get me geolocation accuracy close to Google Maps?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, geolocation, hybrid-mobile-app

I've developed a hybrid app that collects GPS points using a plugin ([this one](https://www.transistorsoft.com/shop/products/cordova-background-geolocation), to be precise). The thing is, when users are on a remote location, with little GPS/network coverage, we've had to resort to opening Google Maps in the background and then using the app in order to get a good coordinate. Otherwise, it doesn't work too well.

I would like to eliminate the need for doing that, but feel at a loss about what kind of practices do apps like Google Maps or Waze do to get better geolocations. Is there a code base that I could study, or some documentation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You may check [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/blob/master/LocationUpdates/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/locationupdates/MainActivity.java). It is ***GitHub*** from ***Google Devs*** and they show how they handle location. Also, you can find other examples [there](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location)